# From outside an object literal foo,how to call an internal function of a method inside foo? (See code below)

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

```js
let foo={
  name:"",
  method:function(){
    function bar(){
      return "bar";
    }
    //bar();   //(2)
  }
};
foo.method.bar(); //(1)
```

(1): throws a Uncaught TypeError: c.method.bar is not a function, I know `foo.method.bar` is searching for a property key/name called `bar` inside `method`, but that does'nt exist, so how do I call `bar` when accessed from outside `foo` without doing this (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current code, it's not possible, because nothing with a reference to `bar` remains after `method` is called, and because `method` doesn't call `bar` itself either.

If you wanted something like this, put `bar` on the outer object so it's exposed:

```js
let foo = {
  name: "",
  bar() {
    return "bar";
  },
  method: function() {

  }
};
console.log(foo.bar());
```

It'd be theoretically possible to put the `bar` function directly onto `method`, but that'd be pretty strange:

```js
let foo = {
  name: "",
  method: function() {

  }
};
foo.method.bar = function() {
  return "bar";
};
console.log(foo.method.bar());
```

Comment: `because nothing with a reference to bar remains after method is called`

Oh yes because the execution context of bar is exited already, after the method call.
`foo.method.bar`

Is this the same as 
`method: { bar:function(){return bar;}}`